# Magento2 category images not showing and not changing

Tags: magento2, category, media

I have a strange problem with Magento 2.2.3. A few month ago we added some category images and they were shown correctly. Today we added some new category images and changes some of the old ones. But no new image is shown and also changed images are not shown. Category page always shows old images ... in admin new category image is correctly shown.

We run reindex, ran:

```
cd httpdocs && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \; \
&& find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \; \
&& chmod u+x bin/magento
```

and also tried to set permissions to 777 of folder and files.

Anyone an idea what is wrong?

Comment: flush cache and check it again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to `System > Cache Management` and scroll to the bottom of the page. Then click the `Flush Catalog Images Cache` button and the clear the other caches.

---

Update: After chat, it turned out that there were image upload at either the website or store scope that were preventing the newly uploaded images from showing.

Comment: I will try it .. but why are new images not shown? cache is cleared ...

Comment: There is a specific button because catalog images do get cached. You may also need to reindex. `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: i allready reindexed several times ...

Comment: is there a possibility to only clear category images and not product images too? because we have thousands of products with each 5 - 8 images ...

Comment: What about checking store scope? Did you check your website view and store view to see if you uploaded an image in those lower scopes? If you did, it would override anything uploaded at the default scope.

Comment: do you mean different store views? we only have 1

Comment: Yes, I mean store views. The fact that you only have 1 store doesn't matter because you can still upload at 3 different scopes. Default, Website, and Store View. You should check all store views just to be sure. This has gotten me several times.

Comment: ... I am in "All Store Views" mode

Comment: I should also mention that if you only have 1 store, you should be only dealing at the default scope. I mention this because I see alot of people with only 1 store view create a maintenance nightmare for themselves by dealing with images and attribute values at store or website level instead of default.

Comment: I understand that. What I am saying is that you should use that same store view selector to check the Website View and the Store View.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day!! I do not know why, but I have to add images not only in "All Store views" but also in "Default Store view" too ...

Comment: No problem at all :-) Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted. If I hadn't been through the same issue 50 times on my own site, I might not have thought of it.

Comment: Someone downvoted me even though I solved your problem. Would you mind giving me an upvote in addition to marking the answer as selected?

Comment: @matin C'mon buddy, a small courtesy in return for some free help. Thanks man.

Comment: @matin i solved your problem but you still haven’t marked my answer as accepted...

Comment: Reindexing worked for me: php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

You can follow my way

1. Remove old image (if exist)
2. Save
3. Upload new image
4. Save
5. Reindex everything about category
6. clear and flush cache