# Magento2 images not loading

Tags: magento2, htaccess, media, pub

I am new to magento, I am building a store in this I have deployed the site in the **domain.com/shop** subfolder, now the problem is that the images are not loading in my site, I think it is due to **.htaccess** file, but I don't have proper understanding in that.

1) Site without **.htaccess** in pub directory

[image]

2) Site with **.htaccess** inside pub directory

[image]

I tried deleting cache, building index, setup:upgrade etc...
Please guide me on this

Adding admin login snapshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System > Cache Management` and scroll to the bottom of the page. Then click the `Flush Catalog Images Cache` button and the clear the other caches.

And refer more link :-

**[Magento2 category images not showing and not changing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224636/magento2-category-images-not-showing-and-not-changing)**

Comment: I am not able to login to admin panel, because it is asking an image captcha and since images are not loading, though I tried deleting the cache using bin/magento cache:flush, cache:clean

Comment: please share the admin login box screenshort

Comment: updated the question with screenshot

Comment: did you got any clues ?

Comment: you create the theme after showing thiis error ??